# Drawing over an image in image view

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have used **imageview** defined in xml to display **.png** image i want to draw lines following the finger over the image . I tried setting onTouchListener() over the image view
but i dont how to proceed further. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying the wrong approach.

To draw lines like that you will need to draw on a canvas. You receive such a canvas in an `onDraw` method.

This means that instead of using a stock `ImageView` you need to create your own `View`, override its `onDraw` method to draw your image and then draw any "lines following the finger over the image". If you want more than the latest line to be visible then you will also need to save those to a canvas that you create so that you will have your onDraw do the following:

1. Draw your original image
2. Draw the canvas containing the old lines
3. Draw the current line.

Given that you will be using your own view you won't use an `onTouchListener()` but instead override the view's `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`.

Looke into Google's API demos Graphics->Fingerpaint (import it with  File -> New -> Other -> Android -> Android Sample Project -> Android X.Y.Z -> API Demos), especially the class `com.example.android.apis.graphics.FingerPaint`.

Additionally, if you want to draw a point when tapping the screen then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251416/android-fingerpaint-sample-does-not-draw-dot) question should be of interest to you.