# creating scratch card android

Tags: android, paint

I'm trying to implement a simple "scratch card". The java code is taken by an android demo about painting ([WHERE to find Android "Fingerpaint" demo? (Android Studio era)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164334/where-to-find-android-fingerpaint-demo-android-studio-era)) and what i want is simply to show the image below the surfaceview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/android"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />

<com.example.jammtup.ErasableView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    /></RelativeLayout>
```

the java code :

```
public class ErasableView extends SurfaceView {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Paint mPaint;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;


public ErasableView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}


public void init() {

    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(64);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

}


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}



private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
} }
```

what i get is a black view not erasable. That does not allow to show the image below.

i need your help !!

Comment: you never do anything with the canvas you draw on.

Comment: can u explain a little bit more.....i'm new in android...

Comment: my bad, I did not see the `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);` line. ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead of your view If you want the whole project just check out my Github repository https://github.com/amarvadla/ScratchCoupon

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.text.TextPaint;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class ScratchTextView extends TextView {

```
Bitmap scratchBitmap;
public interface IRevealListener {
    public void onRevealed(ScratchTextView tv);
    public void onRevealPercentChangedListener(ScratchTextView stv, float percent);
}

public static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 12f;

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

/**
 * Bitmap holding the scratch region.
 */
private Bitmap mScratchBitmap;

/**
 * Drawable canvas area through which the scratchable area is drawn.
 */
public static Canvas mCanvas;

/**
 * Path holding the erasing path done by the user.
 */
private Path mErasePath;

/**
 * Path to indicate where the user have touched.
 */
private Path mTouchPath;

/**
 * Paint properties for drawing the scratch area.
 */
private Paint mBitmapPaint;

/**
 * Paint properties for erasing the scratch region.
 */
private Paint mErasePaint;

/**
 * Gradient paint properties that lies as a background for scratch region.
 */
private Paint mGradientBgPaint;

/**
 * Sample Drawable bitmap having the scratch pattern.
 */
private BitmapDrawable mDrawable;


/**
 * Listener object callback reference to send back the callback when the text has been revealed.
 */
private IRevealListener mRevealListener;

/**
 * Reveal percent value.
 */
private float mRevealPercent;

/**
 * Thread Count
 */
private int mThreadCount = 0;



public ScratchTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();

}

public ScratchTextView(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set);
    init();
}

public ScratchTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

/**
 * Set the strokes width based on the parameter multiplier.
 * @param multiplier can be 1,2,3 and so on to set the stroke width of the paint.
 */
public void setStrokeWidth(int multiplier) {
    mErasePaint.setStrokeWidth(multiplier * STROKE_WIDTH);
}

/**
 * Initialises the paint drawing elements.
 */
private void init() {


    mTouchPath = new Path();

    mErasePaint = new Paint();
    mErasePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mErasePaint.setDither(true);
    mErasePaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mErasePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mErasePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.BEVEL);
    mErasePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mErasePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
            PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    setStrokeWidth(6);

    mGradientBgPaint = new Paint();

    mErasePath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);


    scratchBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.spiderman);
    mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scratchBitmap);


}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mScratchBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mScratchBitmap);

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, mScratchBitmap.getWidth(), mScratchBitmap.getHeight());
    mDrawable.setBounds(rect);

    int startGradientColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary);
    int endGradientColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent);

    mCanvas.drawRect(rect, mGradientBgPaint);
    mDrawable.draw(mCanvas);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mScratchBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mErasePath, mErasePaint);

}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mErasePath.reset();
    mErasePath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}


private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mErasePath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        drawPath();
    }

    mTouchPath.reset();
    mTouchPath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);

}

private void drawPath() {
    mErasePath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mErasePath, mErasePaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mTouchPath.reset();
    mErasePath.reset();
    mErasePath.moveTo(mX, mY);

    checkRevealed();
}

/**
 * Reveals the hidden text by erasing the scratch area.
 */
public void reveal() {

    int[] bounds = getTextBounds(1.5f);
    int left = bounds[0];
    int top = bounds[1];
    int right = bounds[2];
    int bottom = bounds[3];

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
            PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    mCanvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
    checkRevealed();
    invalidate();
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath();
            invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public int getColor() {
    return mErasePaint.getColor();
}


public void setRevealListener(IRevealListener listener) {
    this.mRevealListener = listener;
}

public boolean isRevealed() {
    return mRevealPercent == 1;
}

private void checkRevealed() {

    if(! isRevealed() && mRevealListener != null) {

        int[] bounds = getTextBounds();
        int left = bounds[0];
        int top = bounds[1];
        int width = bounds[2] - left;
        int height = bounds[3] - top;


        // Do not create multiple calls to compare.
        if(mThreadCount > 1) {
            return;
        }

        mThreadCount++;

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Float>() {

            @Override
            protected Float doInBackground(Integer... params) {

                try {
                    int left = params[0];
                    int top = params[1];
                    int width = params[2];
                    int height = params[3];

                    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mScratchBitmap, left, top, width, height);

                    return BitmapUtils.getTransparentPixelPercent(croppedBitmap);
                } finally {
                    mThreadCount--;

                }
            }

            public void onPostExecute(Float percentRevealed) {

                // check if not revealed before.
                if( ! isRevealed()) {

                    float oldValue = mRevealPercent;
                    mRevealPercent = percentRevealed;

                    if(oldValue != percentRevealed) {
                        mRevealListener.onRevealPercentChangedListener(ScratchTextView.this, percentRevealed);
                    }

                    // if now revealed.
                    if( isRevealed()) {
                        mRevealListener.onRevealed(ScratchTextView.this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }.execute(left, top, width, height);

    }
}


private static int[] getTextDimens(String text, Paint paint) {

    int end = text.length();
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, end, bounds);
    int width = bounds.left + bounds.width();
    int height = bounds.bottom + bounds.height();

    return new int[] { width, height};
}

private int[] getTextBounds() {
    return getTextBounds(1f);
}

private int[] getTextBounds(float scale) {

    int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
    int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();

    int vwidth = getWidth();
    int vheight = getHeight();

    int centerX = vwidth/2;
    int centerY = vheight/2;


    TextPaint paint = getPaint();

    String text = getText().toString();

    int[] dimens = getTextDimens(text, paint);
    int width = dimens[0];
    int height = dimens[1];

    int lines = getLineCount();
    height = height * lines;
    width = width / lines;


    int left = 0;
    int top = 0;

    if(height > vheight) {
        height = vheight - ( paddingBottom + paddingTop);
    }
    else {
        height = (int) (height * scale);
    }

    if(width > vwidth) {
        width = vwidth - (paddingLeft + paddingRight);
    }
    else {
        width = (int) (width * scale);
    }

    int gravity = getGravity();


    //todo Gravity.START
    if((gravity & Gravity.LEFT) == Gravity.LEFT) {
        left = paddingLeft;
    }
    //todo Gravity.END
    else if((gravity & Gravity.RIGHT) == Gravity.RIGHT) {
        left = (vwidth - paddingRight) - width;
    }
    else if((gravity & Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) == Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) {
        left = centerX - width / 2;
    }

    if((gravity & Gravity.TOP) == Gravity.TOP) {
        top = paddingTop;
    }
    else if((gravity & Gravity.BOTTOM) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
        top = (vheight - paddingBottom) - height;
    }

    else if((gravity & Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) == Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) {
        top = centerY - height / 2;
    }

    return new int[] {left, top, left + width, top + height};
}
```